# Disable Future Dates on asp:calendar control

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How do I disable future dates on an `asp:calendar` control?

For example, today is October 22 2013, I want to disable dates from October 23 onward, 
and re-enable them when it is the current date.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the DayRender method.

**C# Code Behind**

```
    public void Calendar1_DayRender(object o, DayRenderEventArgs e)
            {


                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;

                //if the days are not part of the current month
                if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
                {  
                    e.Cell.Text = "";
                }
             }
```

Then in the calendar, you need to place

**ASP**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Height="145px" Width="77px" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>
```

You add the OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" to the calendar control.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I misread that. But if you want to just to "enable" the current day and no other days, then this will work..

**Code Behind**

```
public void Calendar1_DayRender(object o, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {


            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;

            if (e.Day.IsToday)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cell.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: @JbMeris Did this solve your problem? Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick to disable future dates in Calendar Control.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Today)
  {

    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, it should be "if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Today)".

Comment: Thank you @Mattzz